# \cite not working for \item in description

Tags: bibtex, citing, description

In a somewhat odd combination of using a bibliography inside a letter (`dinbrief`), a found something odd that I cannot explain:

I had several longer citations in one paragraph that didn't look good, so I transformed the paragraph into a

```
\begin{description}
\item [\cite[some text]{vbg:DGUV-Arbeitsplatz:2015}]
\CITE{(1) Der Unternehmer ...}
\item[\cite[blabla]{BMJV:ArbStV:2004}]
\GQ{(...) \textit{Beim Einrichten...} (...)}
...
\end{description}
```

(`\GQ` just adds German quotes around the argument, and `\CITE` passes `\textit` of the argument to `\GQ`)

Unfortunately the `\cite`s come out as text like `vbg:DGUV-Arbeitsplatz:2015]`.[image]

What did I miss? Don't `[` and `]` nest properly?

When I change `\item[\cite{}]` with `\item cite{}`, then things look correct:[image]

Comment: Try to protect it: `\item[{\cite[some text]{vbg:DGUV-Arbeitsplatz:2015}}]`

Comment: @Sigur Where's your `\protect`? The `{...}`? I didn't know that, but it did work! Please add it as answer so that I can credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first attempt is to protect the citation within braces:

```
\item[{\cite[<some text>]{<some bib>}}]
```

In addition, this trick could be used in theorem blocks, eg,

```
\begin{theorem}[{\cite[<some text>]{<some bib>}}] \end{theorem}
```